# How to globally set a command to execute before each job in Azkaban without modifying project zip files?

Tags: runtime, code-injection, azkaban

I'm working with Azkaban and I'd like to globally set a command to be executed before each job with the type "command". Specifically, I want to insert a piece of code at the beginning of the bash script that is to be executed in the command.

I've asked GPT-4 for advice, and it suggested me to extend the "JobCallback" class and implement the "beforeJobStart" method. However, this doesn't seem to be the right solution.

Also, it's important to note that I cannot modify the zip files of users' projects in bulk.

I have attempted to read the Azkaban source code, particularly the JobRunner and FlowRunner classes, but I couldn't figure out where the zip files are being extracted or find a suitable hook location to insert my code.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this in Azkaban without modifying project zip files? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. modify the method 'getCommandList' in Azkaban job runner
2. modify the mysql table 'project_files' zip_file blog content